# Found a user with the same tp_Login but different tp_SystemId

Tags: user-profile, error, user

I am facing a problem with a user, which worked fine until it has been deleted from the `AD` because he quit. After months he came back, I created again the user in the AD, the `User-Profile-Sync` works fine (no errors), but when he tries to open the SharePoint in Chrome or any other browser it doesn't really work, he gets the error `Sorry, something went wrong` with `File Not Found.` and in the UlsViewer I find the statement `Found a user with the same tp_Login but different tp_SystemId. Try to delete it.`.
Actually, when I try to get the current user using `CSOM` in the browser console, I get `null`. Notice, if I do it on other users it works, so it isn't a code problem.
I used the `SharePointManager` too, the page `https://myportal/my/personal/theUser` is missing. I noticed that there are still personal pages of people who have quit years ago and their users have been deleted from `AD`, so I have no idea why this user is missing and giving problems.

In the list `http://myportal/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx` the user is not present.

If in the powershell I do followings I get `user cannot be found`:

```
Add-PSSnapin *SharePoint*
$web = get-spweb "http://myportal/"
$web.Users.GetByEmail("usersemail@company.com")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/sharepoint-access-denied-error-when-recreating-user-id-in-ad/) article,

Run the below command in SharePoint Management Shell. It will update the tp_SystemID.

```
stsadm.exe -o migrateuser -oldlogin Domainname\OldUserName -newlogin Domainname\NewUserName ?ignoresidhistory
```